# Expression of a matrix in the basis formed by its own eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a square $n\times n$ matrix of complex elements, and let $\{ \vec v \}_{i=1}^n$ $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. Then, if we express $A$ in the basis formed by its eigenvectors, how will $A$ look like in general? Will it be diagonal?

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Very illustrating, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. If you know what is an eigenvector and what "express $A$ in a basis" means, your question is trivial. So I assume that you have difficulties with these notions, so please make your quesion more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Av_i= \lambda_i v_i$ for $i=1,...,n$, then the representation matrix $R$ of $A$ with respect to the basis $\{ \vec v \}_{i=1}^n$ is given by

$$R=diag (\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n).$$

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: Was not me to downvote, but probably it is for the lack of a minimal explanation

Comment: And also one of the risks inherent in answering poor questions.